# How to handle swipe gestures for gridview (android)

Tags: android, eclipse, gridview, swipe, gesture

I have a Gridview in my app and want to capture swipe events on it.
I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures) and used 'OnSwipeTouchListener' class but following error occurred:

> The type OnSwipeTouchListener must implement the inherited abstract
>   method View.OnTouchListener.onTouch(View, MotionEvent)

how can I fix this problem?!

Code:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jessica pls check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures

Comment: My question is exactly about the link you mentioned!!!